# How to hide the detailed processes of Ubuntu startup?

Tags: startup

My Ubuntu never started with a list of detailed process, but after updating 14.04 to 16.04, it started being like that. And I had installed and removed few programs that I don't even know, because I was trying to make `indicator-cpufreq` to work properly and later found out it needed to disable `intel_pstate`. But now I hate it when my laptop starts with those detailed processes. Any suggestions to hide it and start Ubuntu as normal?

The output of `grep DEFAULT /etc/default/grub` is:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_pstate=disable"
```

[image: startup processes details photo]

Comment: What's the output of `grep DEFAULT /etc/default/grub` ? You can [edit] your question to add more information

Comment: You want to add 'quiet' to your boot params, if it's not there ^

Comment: Or you can install any Plymouth theme to hide this

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the messages by editing the configuration file for GRUB. Open a terminal and type

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_pstate=disable"
```

Change it so that it says

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_pstate=disable"
```

Save the file and exit, now type

```
sudo update-grub
```

And reboot

Comment: I did that and still keeps showing the detailed process. :(

Comment: @AkashKunwar is there any splash screen (purple screen, with Ubuntu) at all during boot at any time?

Comment: yeah first comes Purple screen with Ubuntu, then goes to detailed processes list with black screen in background, shows Kernels started etc etc